# Merge unallocated partition with ext4

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have a notebook with dual boot (Windows 8.1 & Ubuntu 16.04). I'm trying to merge an unallocated partition with an ext4 (sda8) partition.Is this possible?

[image]

I'm using a LiveUSB for all the procedure.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a certain definition of "merge" it's possible: you need to move the two partitions next to each other and then you can extend  sda8 with the empty space.

So:

1. Take a back-up
2. move sda6 to the left
3. move sda8 to the left
4. Press "execute" and go sleep
5. next morning, extend sda8

Comment: Thank's for your answer Fabby. But how can I move partitions right or left? Sorry but I'm a newbie.

Comment: You can do it with a mouse. Right-click and select "Move/Resize"

Comment: As you're using a LiveUSB: just click and drag.  For more info [RTFM](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual)  **;-)**

Comment: Pilot6 for a pilot you are really smart! 

Fabby I appreciate your help you are awesome!

Comment: @Costis94: I think Pilot6's comment is good!  That's why I upvoted it... [evil grin]